# Doctrine 2 relationship is not working

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have Item entity:

```
/**
 * Item
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="item")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Item {
...
    /**
     * @var Unit
     * @ORM\Column(name="unitId", type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Unit", inversedBy="items")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="unitId", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $unit;
...
}
```

And Unit entity:

```
/**
 * Unit
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="unit")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Unit {
...
    /**
     * @var Item[]
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Item", mappedBy="unit")
     */
    private $items;
...
}
```

And a code like:

```
$item = $this->objectManager->getRepository('Application\Main\Entity\Item')->find($id);
$unitName = $item->getUnit()->getName();
```

Which produces error `Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object`, what means that doctrine handles this field as simple field, not a relation field. What should I do to force Doctrine to use this field as a relationship? I have few entities with such issue, while other are working just fine. What is the reason?

Comment: Are you sure that the `unit` field in the `Item` entity is not NULL and that the `Unit`, which the item references, exists? Does the database structure reflect the code?

Comment: @GentiSaliu `$item->getUnit()` returns integer. I use `orm:schema-tool:update` to make sure that schema is synced, and, as I see, everything is ok. But there are no foreign keys that doctrine usually creates for relations

Comment: Have you tried `orm:schema-tool:update --force`? Also try `orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql` to check whether the foreign keys are being created.

Comment: I don't actually know how Doctrine and Zend work together, but clearing the cache (Doctrine/Zend) could also be something worth trying.

Comment: @GentiSaliu Thank you very much, but I think I found what caused issue. I tried to clear cache etc before looking to sources and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDrive.php`, lines 262-263:

```
// Field can only be annotated with one of:
// @Column, @OneToOne, @OneToMany, @ManyToOne, @ManyToMany
```

So, it seems that you cannot use relation annotations when using `@Column` and visa versa. I had to remove `@Column` annotation and add `@JoinColumn` annotation and it started to work as expected.